# videojs - How to catch custom http error codes during live stream?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, http-live-streaming, video.js

I have a live stream (HLS) that I am playing using videojs 6.8. For some users, after the playback has started (about 4-5 `.ts` files have been loaded) the server throws me a `409` error.

How do I catch this specific error code so that I can programmatically stop the playback and show an error message?

Currently, videojs keeps trying to resume playback indefinitely. I have tried `retryplaylist`, `blacklistplaylist` but all the info I get is that the playlist has been blacklisted and is being retried, I do not see the HTTP code anywhere in my `console.log()`. `player.on('error')` doesn't throw any error. I have tried all three of the following but none of them gives me the http code:

```
    player.on('error', function (e) {
        // no log
        console.log(e);
    })

     player.tech().on('retryplaylist', function (e, data) {
       // logs that it is being retried, but no http code
       console.log('retry');
       console.log(e);
     })

    player.tech().on('usage', function (e, data) {
        // logs the even 'retryplaylist` but does not give me a http code.
        console.log('usage');
        console.log(e)
    })
```

I do not want to put my message in `retryplaylist` because that event will be thrown in case of a slow network too (I already tested this).

What do I have to do to catch the specific 409 error?

Comment: Have you tried modifying the [XHR function](https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming#hlsxhr) to handle these errors? A relatively safe option could be to wrap the base `xhr` function with logic to catch a `409` and handle it appropriately.

Comment: hi, thank you for the reply. is there any documentation for the XHR function? seems like there's no `status` property for this?

Comment: You would need to create a module that functionally replaces the [XHR module](https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming/blob/master/src/xhr.js) currently in Video.js, then override that on the player object.

Comment: Jesus, all this to catch a measly error code. Surely the gods of videojs have something better to offer.

Comment: I have same issue. Did anyone solved this issue? Please! Want to fix this urgent task.

Answer (score 0):

Look like:

```
var retries = 0;
player.tech().on('retryplaylist', function (e, data) {
  retries++;
  if (retries >= 3) {
    // do something
  }
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.